# Speed up select distinct process from very large table

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

I want to use select distinct on a single variable to extract data from a very large MyISAM table with ~300 million rows (~ 12.3 GiBs in size -- select distinct should yield ~100k observations, so much smaller than 1 GiB).

The problem is, this query takes 10+ hours to run. I actually don't know how long it takes because I've never finished the process due to impatience.

My query is as follows:

```
create table codebook(
symbol varchar(16) not null);
create index IDXcodebook on codebook(symbol);
insert into codebook
select distinct(symbol) from bigboytable
```

I've tried an indexon bigboytable(symbol) to speed up the process, but I have ran that indexing code for 15+ hours with no end in sight.

I've also tried:

```
SELECT symbol from bigboytable, GROUP BY symbol
```

But I get

> Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

in fact, if any query, in this project or in other projects, is "too complicated", I get Error Code 2013 after only ~1-6+ hours, depending.

Other settings are:

Migration connection timeout (3600); DBS connection read timeout skipped; DBMS connection keep-alive interval (5 seconds);  SSH BufferSize (10240 bytes); SSH connect, read write, and command timeouts (500 seconds);.

Any suggestions? I might work with Python's MySQL packages if that might speed things up; Workbench is very slow. I need this data ASAP for a large project, but don't need the 300+ million observations from bigboytable.

Edit: I attach my bigboytable definition and explain output here.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The index on codebook will actually slow down inserts - consider not applying that index until the table is built.

Comment: Is your table of concern codebook or bigboytable?  Let's deal with a single table to start with.   After you decide, please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable; and B) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'mytable';  for us to see what you are really dealing with.

Comment: Thinking more, I think you're gong to have to bite at least one bullet: move the db to a machine with more resources; wait for that index to finish (knowing it will slow down future inserts into bigboytable); and/or recognize that you have reached the limit of that software and move your data to something built for data that size.

Comment: @Jerry do you think Python's MySQL would do better, or is it the same thing? Will I have to export the table to csv (or another file) just to use it in a different dataset?

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question. And I agree with @Jerry that your MySQL server machine is too small. It's also possible it's misconfigured so it uses a /tmp RAMdisk for its sorting table-spill. ANd no, hittng MySQL with python won't help.

Comment: I've edited my question as requested.